# Wrong object is returned from a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Those are the model definitions:

```
# tagging.rb
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belong_to :item, polymorphic: true
end

# product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings, as: :item
end

# taggings_controller.rb
def index
  item = params[:item_type].constantize.find(params[:item_id])
  # the or clause brings results that are not related to the item
  # SQL: SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE ("taggings"."item_id" = ? AND "taggings"."item_type" = ? OR "taggings"."context_type" = ? AND "taggings"."context_id" = ?)
  @taggings = item.taggings.or(Tagging.where(context_type: item.class.to_s, context_id: item.id))
    debugger
  super
end
```

The debugging log:

```
(byebug) @taggings.pluck(:item_type)
["Feed", "Product", "Post"]

(byebug) @taggings.map { |tagging| tagging.item.class.to_s }
["Product", "Product", "Product"]
```

As you see, when I'm trying to access the associated item of a tagging, I'm getting an incorrect item. I was able to resolve this using `item.reload` but that doesn't seem to be very efficient since the documentation says it performs an additional `select` query to get the attributes. Can anyone please help me understand why is this happening and how to solve this?

Comment: What does your `OR` condition say when fetching the taggings? Or you can also share the output of `@taggings.to_sql`

Comment: @Deepesh Yes, I've edited the post, but generally it looks for taggings with context type and id as the item (no rails/db associations there).

Comment: What is the difference between `item_type` and `context_type`?  is the problem here in the first example, you have records where `item_type=Feed` and `context_type=Product` and that is somehow producing the disconnect?  definitely a little strange.  `Feed` and `Post` are *not* somehow subclasses of `Product`, right?

Comment: @mrrogers Item is a polymorphic association, and the context is just two regular columns without any association or constraints. I've noticed that if I reverse the order in the `or` clause, it works as well, I just can't understand why.

Comment: I suspect the query generated is incorrect, `("taggings"."item_id" = ? AND "taggings"."item_type" = ? OR "taggings"."context_type" = ? AND "taggings"."context_id" = ?)` the `OR` and `AND` are messing up. Try querying manually instead of association something like: `Tagging.where(item: item).or(Tagging.where(context_type: item.class.to_s, context_id: item.id))`